# React.Js: Prevent onClick-events of siblings while a onClick is executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what's the best practice for the following problem?

I have a parent component **(Board)** and four child components **(GameButton)** which are buttons that one can click on. The button click illuminates the button for 0,5s and then turns the button back to the initial style. I want to prevent any clicks on other buttons while one button is illuminated.

```
class GameButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      illuminated:false,
    };
    this.playButton = this.playButton.bind(this);
  }

  playButton(){

    if (this.props.gameActive && this.props.clickable){
      // lock all other buttons until this function is done executing
      this.props.toggleButtonAccess();
      console.log(this.props.clickable);

      // pass the second state update in a callback function to ensure delayed execution
      this.setState({illuminated:true}, function() {
        // arrow function to prevent binding of this to window
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({illuminated: false});
        this.props.toggleButtonAccess();
        console.log(this.props.clickable);

      },500);
      });
    }

  }
  render() {
    var buttonStyle = this.props.colorClass; 
    if (this.state.illuminated){
      buttonStyle += " illuminated-" + this.props.color;
      console.log(buttonStyle);
    }
    return (
        <div className={buttonStyle} onClick={this.playButton}></div>
    );
  }
}


class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      gameActive:true,
    };
    this.toggleButtonAccess = this.toggleButtonAccess.bind(this);
  }

  toggleButtonAccess(){
    this.clickable = (this.clickable) ? false : true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className ="game-container">
       <GameButton colorClass="game-btn green" color="green" clickable={this.clickable} toggleButtonAccess={this.toggleButtonAccess}/>
        <GameButton colorClass="game-btn red" color="red" clickable={this.clickable} toggleButtonAccess={this.toggleButtonAccess}/>
       <GameButton colorClass="game-btn yellow" color="yellow" clickable={this.clickable} toggleButtonAccess={this.toggleButtonAccess}/>
       <GameButton colorClass="game-btn blue" color="blue" clickable={this.clickable} toggleButtonAccess={this.toggleButtonAccess}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So far I tried to do it by having the property **this.clickable** on the parent (Board) component and then toggle it on and off every time a button is clicked with **toggleAccessButton()**. However, this is not working. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should make `clickable` a part of the parent state. Also, `button` HTML elements have `disabled` attributes that will be disabled if the expression in it evaluates to `true`. So your `GameButton` could have `disabled={this.props.clickable}` in the rendered `button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things that you need to change. First, in GameButton, I don't see value in `gameActive`. In fact, you don't pass any value to this prop. If it doesn't have anything other purpose which you haven't mentioned here, simply remove it.

```
class GameButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      illuminated:false,
    };
    this.playButton = this.playButton.bind(this);
  }

  playButton(){

    if (this.props.clickable){
      // lock all other buttons until this function is done executing
      this.props.toggleButtonAccess();
      console.log(this.props.clickable);

      // pass the second state update in a callback function to ensure delayed execution
      this.setState({illuminated:true}, function() {
        // arrow function to prevent binding of this to window
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({illuminated: false});
        this.props.toggleButtonAccess();
        console.log(this.props.clickable);

      },500);
      });
    }

  }
  render() {
    var buttonStyle = this.props.colorClass; 
    if (this.state.illuminated){
      buttonStyle += " illuminated-" + this.props.color;
      console.log(buttonStyle);
    }
    return (
        <div className={buttonStyle} onClick={this.playButton}></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now in Board component, you need to keep `clickable` in you state and use `setState` to change it in `toggleButtonAccess`. Here also I don't understand why you have `gameActive` in the state.

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      gameActive:true,
      clickable:true
    };
    this.toggleButtonAccess = this.toggleButtonAccess.bind(this);
  }

  toggleButtonAccess(){
    this.setState({clickable:!this.state.clickable});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className ="game-container">
       <GameButton colorClass="game-btn green" color="green" clickable={this.clickable} toggleButtonAccess={this.toggleButtonAccess}/>
        <GameButton colorClass="game-btn red" color="red" clickable={this.clickable} toggleButtonAccess={this.toggleButtonAccess}/>
       <GameButton colorClass="game-btn yellow" color="yellow" clickable={this.clickable} toggleButtonAccess={this.toggleButtonAccess}/>
       <GameButton colorClass="game-btn blue" color="blue" clickable={this.clickable} toggleButtonAccess={this.toggleButtonAccess}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Assuming that you have setup other things correctly, it should work now as expected.

Comment: Yes sorry, when creating the MWE I forgot to delete the gameActive-state.

Answer (score 1):

i would prefer to use React state.
In my example i toggle cssClass.
Here code example:

```
    const ButtonComponent = ({className,handler,idx}) => {
     return ( < div className = {
      className
    } >
    < button onClick = {
      handler
    } > {
      idx
    } < /button> < /div >);
};

class HolderComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        current: null
      }

    }

    handler(e, idx) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(idx + "CURRENT");
      this.setState({
        current: idx
      }, () => {
        const self = this;
        setTimeout(() => {
          self.setState({
            current: null
          });
        }, 1000)
      });
    }

    getButtons(props = []) {

      return props.map((btn, idx) => this.getButton(idx));

    }

    getButton(idx) {

        return ( < ButtonComponent key = {
            idx + "uniqKey"
          }
          className = {
            this.state.current === idx ? "test" : "testActive"
          }
          handler = {
            (e) => this.handler(e, idx)
          }
          isActive = {
            this.state.current === idx
          }
          idx = {
            idx
          }
          />)
        }

        render() {
          return ( < div > {
              this.getButtons([1, 2, 3, 4])
            } < /div>);

          }

        }

        ReactDOM.render( < HolderComponent / > , document.getElementById("app"));
```